# Equivalent of SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA for IIS6

Tags: c++, iis-6, isapi

I really would like the raw Read data off of  SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA  but it is no longer supported in IIS6 without enabling IIS5 isolation mode which I do not want to do. Is there an equivalent to this line of code that works for IIS6?

```
DWORD CTryISAPIFilter::OnReadRawData(CHttpFilterContext* pCtxt,PHTTP_FILTER_RAW_DATA pRawData)
{
      char *Data;
         Data = (char *) pRawData->pvInData;    
         strRequestRawData = Data;
         return SF_STATUS_REQ_NEXT_NOTIFICATION;
}
```

This is the MSDN Article [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cde42787-982a-478c-b319-e703b270d8ee.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, basically IIS6 no longer supports that function because of the parallized way IIS6 handles data. In order to capture the request body you have to use http modules, however you can still capture all the responses by using the OnWriteRawData function.